# How to assign a hyperlink and an onaction event to a shapes object in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In microsoft excel vba, I am attempting to assign hyperlinks and/or actions to shapes I have drawn.  Here is roughly what I have tried (uncomment only one line at a time)

Basically, what I want to do is allow users to get more information by clicking on a shape object.  Hyperlinks are fine, but some kind of event handler which accepts parameters would be ideal.   I will be creating hundreds of these shapes, and they need to link to unique places in the document.

```
  Dim destinationHyperlinkCell as Range
  set destinationHyperlinkCell = Range("10:10")
  ' (do some stuff here)...
  With Sheet1.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                      600, _
                      600, _
                      300, _
                      16)
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test this thing"
    .Name = destinationHyperlinkCell.Address & " group of shapes"
    '.Hyperlink.Address = destinationHyperlinkCell.Address
    '.Hyperlink.Range = destinationHyperlinkCell.Address
    '.OnAction = "'showDebugMsg """ & .Name & """'"
  End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "Assign Macro ..." to define a macro to each shape which fires on "Click"

You can use the same macro for each shape and use the `Application.Caller` property to get the name of the shape which fired the macro. Then you have all the ingredients to write an intelligent handler - like a (hidden) Excel table that resolves shape name into an URL, text or whatever

```
Sub Shape_Click()
    MsgBox "Co-Cooo! from" & Application.Caller
End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Good luck - MikeD

Comment: Thanks!  With the Application.Caller I have the flexibility I need.  Now the code above is " .OnAction = Shape_Click() "...